# Real cost associated with Firebase or AWS game project back ends

Tags: server, costs

I have been looking for answers to how much does it really cost for using systems such as Firebase or AWS for deployment. We have several games apps and web games we want to deploy this year. Some will have a shared/global high score system, Name storage, achievement storage etc... and we believe Firebase or AWS is a better and secure solution than just our server which we will use for serving the projects (for now).

I want to present a realistic budget. I have used the "estimate" function, but that doesn't feel real. Sometimes it is too good to be true, other times its like "ooohhhh!" I never used these services for production before and would appreciate any guidance and experience someone has had before when it comes to cost.

I sincerely apologize if this is not the proper forum for this question.

Comment: Have you looked at brainCloud?

Comment: @EdMarty this is great. We are looking at this. It is a very nice near all in one type of solution with upfront costs.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of a case where the Estimate function is giving you an answer you don't believe is accurate? This would let users here either confirm its accuracy / inaccuracy or suggest a more accurate estimation method for that case.